# Is Fundamental Groups (Algebraic Topology) sufficient for graduate programme interview?

Tags: phd, mathematics, interview

Is Fundamental Groups sufficient for graduate programme interview?

Suppose if someone is going to  complete  master program  and planning to do PhD. He/she is doing preparation for PhD interview(viva).

In PhD interview  he/she chooses two topics Algebra and Topology.

In algebra: linear algebra, group theory and ring theory.

In topology: point set topology and algebraic topology.

Algebraic topology is a very hard subject and contain many topics like  fundamental groups, homology, cohomology etc.

**My confusion**: Suppose if professor asked to the candidate    do you read in algebraic topology ?

Suppose he/she said  yes.

Suppose he/she has read only about fundamental groups topics but  didn't read homology, cohomology topics, etc.

**My first question** : Can we choose only fundamental groups and skip the other topics like homology, cohomology  in algebraic topology for Phd program interviews?

Or  do we have to read fundamental  group, homology etc

**My second question** : Is there  will be any  negative impact if he/she says to the professor  that I have read only about fundamental groups in algebraic topology  due to lack of time?

Comment: I think we might need a little more info here as to context.  Interviews for acceptance to a PhD program is not universal across the globe, so knowing a bit more about the typical requirements in your part of the world would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of many PhD programs that would require an incoming student to be broadly read on the entirety of algebraic topology (or any other large subject matter) as an entrance requirement.

I also have never given nor received a PhD application interview that required the student to go into specific knowledge on topics that he or she is not familiar with.

When I was a PhD applicant (this was in the U.S. and I know Europe has a different approach), I was interviewed by many professors at different schools. Their focus always was on letting me explain what I (emphasis) knew and what I (emphasis) was interested in. I never was quizzed or tested on topics that were not familiar to me.

Even in a viva, I do not believe that they will just begin throwing out every tricky question they can think of. Most schools have a specific syllabus of topics that they will expect you to be familiar with.